# Please install an MTA on this system if you want to use sendmail!

Tags: php, cron, mail

I get this message in `/var/log/apache2/error.log` everytime a cronjob on my desktop wgets a php page that tries to send an email.

How can I install a dummy so this message is gone?

I already have installed `lsb-invalid-mta` but still.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, you don't want this php page to actually try to send emails. So try any of these:

- delete that php page, which is useless anyway since you don't intend to have a mailer
- correct the page so that a simple wget doesn't trigger mail sending (which seems very wrong)
- list the page in /robots.txt, which wget respects (unless told not to)
- tell wget to ignore the directory this file is in. (Unfortunately, it seems that wget cannot exclude specific files).